# MaterialUI icons and build bundle size

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I am currently building a menu that is rendered based on "config" object.

The config has properties as follows:

```
interface MenuItem {
  label: string;
  icon: string,
  to?: string;
  isLastOfKind?: boolean;
  submenu?: Array<MenuItem>;
}
```

My problem here is that when I use `import { asyncComponent } from 'react-async-component'` I am getting a large build bundle and I'd love to handle it differently. Is there any way that comes to your mind other than

```
const MaterialIconAsync: React.FC<{ iconName: string }> = ({ icon }) => {
  return <>
    {React.createElement(asyncComponent({
      resolve: () => import(
        /* webpackMode: "eager" */
        `@material-ui/icons/${iconName}`)
    }))}
  </>
}
```

I will attach current bundle size as it is enormous and takes quite a while to build using my runner in gitlabCI. I've red about [treeshaking](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/) and tried another approach with just importing
`* as Icons` and then Icons[iconName] but the result was still not what I'd expect.

Thanks in advance!

[image]